# Extension expiration date (PTE)

Tags: dynamics-business-central, businesscentral

I want to to know if there is a way to set an **expiration date** for extensions in business centra deployed by uploading the app file (PTE Scope).

So that the customer will be asked to enter a key to unable the extension after every delay expiration.

the problem is that if i want to generate a different key every time the delay expires  i should have access to the extension but in this case if i gave the app file to the customer how could i provide this key again?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a licensing engine yourself.

A simple solution could be:

1. Create and Azure Function that accepts a license key and returns if the license is valid and/or active.
2. Add the possibility to enter at license key in your PTE app.
3. At key points in your code (opening of certain pages or execution of specific functions/reports) you add a check that calls the Azure Function to verify the license
4. Provide the license key to your customer

For step 3 you should implement a fail safe in case your Azure Function goes offline or the Business Central service for some reason cannot call an external API.